# Printing in JavaScript is not working fine?

Tags: javascript, variables, printing

I know that their is nor difference between the Outputs for
`var carName = "Volvo XC60";`
`var carName = 'Volvo XC60';`

This code is giving the Output `'He is called "Johnny"'`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
        var answer2 = "'He is called "Johnny"'";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = answer2
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and This code below is not giving the Output, why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
        var answer2 = '"He is called 'Johnny'"';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = answer2
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"This code is giving the Output 'He is called "Johnny"'"* - No it isn't. Both versions have syntax errors and neither will work. If the string literal is quoted with double quotes, you can't have double quotes *in* the string unless they are escaped with backslashes, and similarly if quoted with singles, you can't have singles *in* the string without escaping them.

Comment: @nnnnnn I worked,

Comment: If you use double quotes to wrap the string and wish to use double quotes within the string you must backslash them! `"He is called \"Johnny\"";` if you want to use single quotes then this should be just fine `'He is called "Johnny"';` Please note that a sting like `'Johnny's cat is white'` you will also need to backslash the single quote if you wrap that with single quotes. `'Johnny\'s cat is white'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
        var answer2 = '"He is called \'Johnny\'"';
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = answer2
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code is giving the me correct after using the backslashes

Comment: That doesn't work. You've escaped the wrong quotes. It should be `'"He is called \'Johnny\'"'`

Comment: I think you'll find that is incorrect. it should be `'"He is called \'Johnny\'"'` assuming you want the output to display **"He is called 'Johnny'"**